# Wrapping around on a list when list index is out of range

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for some code improvement, or a pre-built version of what I've implemented myself as I think there might be, or should be, a cleaner way to achieve what I want.

I'm writing a piece of software to convert guitar tabs into classical notation, I need to convert the number on a tab to it's corresponding note and it would be useful for building a list of each strings note from the starting string.

I have a list of notes, (a - g#) and a list of frets (0, 21).

Notes[fret] works fine for the first eleven notes but after that I obviously get an out of index error.

The code I have to get around this is here:

```
notes = ["a", "a#", "b", "c", "c#", "d", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#"]
note = 21
while note >= len(notes):
    note -= 11
    try:
        print notes[note]
    except:
        continue
```

It works but it seems a little long, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Aren't you forgetting "d#" ?  If so, using '%' like "notes[note % len(notes)]" is a good way to go, as it'll automatically correct for changing list sizes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the [`%` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to produce a modulus:

```
notes[note % len(notes)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> notes = ["a", "a#", "b", "c", "c#", "d", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#"]
>>> note = 21
>>> notes[note % len(notes)]
'g#'
```

or in a loop:

```
>>> for note in range(22):
...     print notes[note % len(notes)],
... 
a a# b c c# d e f f# g g# a a# b c c# d e f f# g g#
```

Answer (score 5):

Another options is to use [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> notes = ["a", "a#", "b", "c", "c#", "d", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#"]

>>> frets = range(21)
>>> for note, fret in itertools.izip(itertools.cycle(notes), frets):
        print ("[%s, %d]" %(note, fret))

[a, 0]
[a#, 1]
[b, 2]
[c, 3]
[c#, 4]
[d, 5]
[e, 6]
[f, 7]
[f#, 8]
[g, 9]
[g#, 10]
[a, 11]
[a#, 12]
[b, 13]
[c, 14]
[c#, 15]
[d, 16]
[e, 17]
[f, 18]
[f#, 19]
[g, 20]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator:

```
In [3]: notes = ["a", "a#", "b", "c", "c#", "d", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#"]

In [4]: len(notes)
Out[4]: 11

In [5]: note = 11

In [6]: notes[note]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-707e7e351463> in <module>()
----> 1 notes[note]

IndexError: list index out of range

In [7]: notes[note%len(notes)]
Out[7]: 'a'

In [8]: notes[note-11]
Out[8]: 'a'
```