# How to begin from start once index out of range - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of items:

```
items = [a, b, c, d]
```

I need it to be so that if I say `items[4]` which isn't in the list, the returned element should be the first element only, which is `a`, like a loop, instead of a `IndexError: index out of range` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping around on a list when list index is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122623/wrapping-around-on-a-list-when-list-index-is-out-of-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ operator %:

```py
def getItem(items, index):
    return items[index % len(items)]

items = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’]
print(getItem(items, 42))
```

Output:

```
c
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error message, you can handle it as an exception for the indexes not in array's range. i.e. if the index entered is `n` then

```
try:
    print(items[n])
except:
    print(items[n % len(items)])
```

I hope this helped..!