# Restarting at the beginning of the list

Tags: python

I want to index the beginning of a list incase there is an index which is outside the bounds of the list.

For example:-

```py
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

If I have a list called alphabet and then I want to move 2 spots after `"y"`,  how do I make it so that if it exceeds the bounds of the list, i.e, it exceeds `"z"`, then I want it to start at the beginning of the list which in this case is `"a"`? So if I want to move 5 spots from `"y"`, it should point at `"e"`.

I tried creating more and more loops to solve this issue, however I'm just not sure on what to type so that it starts at the beginning of the list.

Comment: read about modulo

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122623/wrapping-around-on-a-list-when-list-index-is-out-of-range
I think it answers your question

Comment: Mod the index by the length of the list: `alphabet[i % len(alphabet)]`